# submit file in form in twig and get local path in controller symfony2

Tags: php, file, symfony, controller, twig

**I have this form in a twig**:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path("enviar") }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

**And in the controller I have**:

```
/**
* @Route("/enviar", name="enviar")
* @Method("POST")
*/
public function enviar(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->request->get('foto');
    return new Response('full path of file in your desktop is: ' . $this->getFullPath($file));
}
```

I need to get the full path of the file. For example if I upload the file from C:\files\foto.jpg, I need to print in response **C:\files\foto.jpg**.

**thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

You will never have access to the full path for file that user wants to upload. You can retrieve only original filename and the temporary filename for uploaded file.

Check documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php